# Can I buy email address for my new domain?

Tags: email

I've purchased a domain for a website that I will host on AWS but I could not figure out how to create a custom email address for this domain. I would like to have something like  marketing@domain.com.
Is it possible to do this?
Thanks

Comment: AWS has two email services SES (programmatic sending/receiving) and AWS Workmail (end-user email boxes)

Comment: Your domain provider may also offer an email hosting service. Or look into an [email hosting provider](https://www.techradar.com/news/best-email-hosting-providers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. AWS has two services for email, [Amazon Simple Simple Email Service (SES)](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) and [Amazon Workmail](https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/).

These two services can both send and receive email, but they are designed for different purposes. You can read more about each in the links above, and decide which one is best for you.

Its worth pointing out that you can host your mail with any provider. You can do this by setting the MX records in your DNS to the values that the  mail host you select provides. Common choices for hosting mail, that are similarly priced to Amazon Workmail, are [Google Workspaces](https://workspace.google.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=na-CA-all-en-dr-skws-all-all-trial-%7Bmatchtype%7D-dr-1009892&utm_content=text-ad-none-any-DEV_%7Bdevice%7D-CRE_%7Bcreative%7D-ADGP_Smartphone%20%7C%20SEM%20%7C%20SKWS%20%7C%20BMM%20%7C%20Email-KWID_43700059986636786-%7Btargetid%7D&utm_term=KW_%7Bkeyword%7D-ST_%2Bemail&gclsrc=aw.ds&&gclid=CjwKCAiAjeSABhAPEiwAqfxURbp_l1KpJ0pLVToly194bFfLw8K659Uct_r5zO3XaXEkrKrRFLMCghoCYv8QAvD_BwE) (which is gmail with your own custom domain), Microsoft365, and GoDaddy has an email only plan, but there are myriad of providers that offer mail for your custom domain.